# Can Worklight http adapter load open data format like JSON , xml, csv?

Tags: json, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, opendata

I have a open data link below

http://data.ntpc.gov.tw/NTPC/od/data/api/IMC14?$format=xml

How to create worklight http adapter get json object? Then using json object let it to dojo mobile!

I have ever see a example using jquery link to open data api. But not ever see using dojo mobile link open data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Read the [Getting Started modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development) and try the code samples. Specifically I would recommend:

- Adapter framework overview
- HTTP adapter – Communicating with HTTP back-end systems
- Invoking adapter procedures from client applications.

Also take a look at the documentation [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_DevelopingTheServer-sideOfAnIBMWorklightApplication.html). There's an example with Worklight + Dojo Mobile [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/WorklightStarter_DojoMobile.zip).

Comment: I have found a very good example is like my question. The link is bleow

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/using_ibm_worklight_http_adapters_with_rest_json_services7?lang=en